# Where is TShellTreeView?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, delphi-10-seattle

I'm trying to compile an old project in Delphi 10 Seattle and get the following error message

> class TShellTreeView not found click cancel to ignore.....

`TShellTreeView` is a design-time component, part of the `ShellCtrls` package, that always shipped with Delphi in the `Samples` packages typically found in :

> C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\xx.x\Samples\Object Pascal\VCL\

Now it doesn't seem to be there anymore.  Where did this package go?

Comment: The sample applications are an optional part of the installation. If you did not install them, they won't be there. So I guess that `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\Samples` does not exist on your machine?

Comment: As you can see `....\Samples\Object Pascal\VCL\` till here its there as you can see `samples' is there`

Comment: Can someone please help?

Comment: *"As you can see"* Actually no, I cannot see what is installed on your machine.

Comment: "WHy" - The -1 wasn't me but maybe because your q shows zero research effort and then within an hour of posting it, you come back pestering readers for help.  Why should readers put themselves out if you can't be bothered to?

Comment: FWIW, found the XE5 project here: `C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\Samples\Delphi\VCL\ShellControls`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ShellControls` design-time package, along with a number of other very old items in the `Samples` package were removed in XE7+.

If you want a ready-made design-time package, you can still get the last version shipped with XE6 in the [SourceForge repository here](http://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RadStudio_XE6/Object%20Pascal/VCL/ShellControls/).

The relevant documentation page that links to this repository is [the XE6-specific page.](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE6/en/Category:Sample)  Documentation pages specific to later versions of Delphi will link to the new `Samples` repositories specific to those versions.  To install the package, open the `vclshlctrls.dproj` file, right-click the `ShellControls.bpl` package in the `Project Manager` and select `Install`.

Keep in mind that this is now an abandoned package - you may need to make changes to compile it in newer versions.

---

The current, updated, `.pas` files have, however, been integrated into the VCL source.  The best option is probably to make your own design-time package out of these.  To do this you will need to find the sources in :

> Vcl.Shell.ShellConsts.pas
>     Vcl.Shell.ShellCtrls.pas
>
> in  :
>
> [**ProgramFiles**]\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\source\vcl\

- Next, copy these to a working directory for your new package.
- Create a new package (File -> New -> Package)
- Save the package as `ShellControls.bpl` in your working directory and add the two source files.
- Edit your working copy of `Vcl.Shell.ShellCtrls.pas` to add as the last item in the `interface` section :

  ```
  procedure Register;
  ```
- And add as the first item in the `implementation` section :

  ```
  procedure Register;
  begin
    RegisterComponents('Shell Controls', [TShellListView]);
    RegisterComponents('Shell Controls', [TShellTreeView]);
    RegisterComponents('Shell Controls', [TShellChangeNotifier]);
  end;
  ```
- Save the package.  Right-click, the `.bpl` in the Project Manager and select -> `Install`.  Accept any required references the IDE notifies you about and you should be done.

Comment: Your edit of the question makes my answer look strange, no? Are the shell controls provided with the Delphi source different from the ones you refer to?

Comment: @TomBrunberg Your answer is wrong - those source files simply are not there anymore.  They stopped being provided with Delphi after XE6, as I said.  OP's question was specifically that he couldn't find the sources where they used to be - I just cleaned up the clumsiness of the question.  If you want them, you have to go and get them from the XE6 Samples distribution.  That said, even if the source files were there, it's not enough to simply add the unit to the `uses` clause as you suggest - these are optional packages that you have to compile and install first.

Comment: The two files (one including the `TShellTreeView` asked for) are definitely in the location I said, in my XE5 to XE 10 installations.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Are you sure you didn't put them there yourself?  Maybe have an in-house installer that added them for you?  The standard installer, afaik, does not contain them anymore.  Certainly mine didn't.  The only reference I can find is here : https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=677309

Comment: Absolutely sure they were installed by the RAD Studio installer. So you say that your source directory doesn't have `Vcl.Shell.ShellConsts` and `Vcl.Shell.ShellCtrls`?

Comment: @TomBrunberg AH! Ok, we're talking about totally different things.  Yes, those files are in my vcl source directory.  But those are just the `.pas` files - they're not the complete design-time package.  I guess they would let you still compile old units but I'm not sure they would let you view or edit forms that used the design-time components.  I've edited OP's question to replace the error message.

Comment: It seems we were and your answer def. deserves my +1.

Comment: @TomBrunberg And yours mine - I completely blanked out the middle part of the path! Learned something new.

Comment: Parts of your answer are wrong. The package is not  there anymore, but the controls still are. They were not deprecated, they were upgraded to become VCL proper.

Comment: J..., I deleted my answer because it didn't answer even closely the actual reason for OPs problem, as @KenWhite pointed out in a comment to me.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I've expanded my answer with another option to use those sources to build a new design-time package.

Comment: FWIW, one can also use the `Component -> Install component` wizard.in the IDE. I actually [wrote that thing](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/compinstall.html). It does what you do manually. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yeah, that works too.  Still need to edit in the `Register` method.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the Help. This worked like Charm. the Edit from J.... Helped a lot Thank you very much. I am pretty new to Delphi. And Stack Overflow has always been there for rescue. Thanks

Comment: If you do not find the Files in the Location mentioned above you can always download it from the sourceforge repository `http://svn.code.sf.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/branches/RadStudio_XE6/Object%20Pascal/VCL/` Check for `ShellControls/`

Comment: Where To save a Package File? Location

Answer (score 0):

According to docs copy of the Samples is here: http://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/ This is SVN repository, so you will have to use Version Control IDE plugin or separate app to get sources.

Comment: No 'ShellCntrl` there also

Comment: Difficult to understand the upvote here. You say that the documentation links to this sourceforge repo, but you don't give a link to that documentation, and indeed the repo does not contain the code in question.