# Hide root path/folder in DirectoryListBox Delphi

Tags: delphi

First excuse me, i use google translation, i am french ...

With delphi (Berlin) how to hide the parents (root) ?

For example, if I put `DirectoryListBox1.Directory := 'documentation\';`
(c:\test\documentation), how to make c:\test not appear but only the "documentation" folder (and all the folders that it contains)?

Example 1

[image]

Example 2

[image]

Thank you in advance for your answer

Answer (score 1):

The `TDirectoryListBox` component does not support what you are trying to do.

I would suggest using `TShellTreeView` instead; it has similar functionality, looks more modern, and among other things behaves the way you want if you set the `Root` property.

If you are using XE6 or earlier you should have direct access to this component, if you're on a later version you'll have to follow the steps in the accepted answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905926/where-is-tshelltreeview) to install them.

Comment: Hello

Thank you very much for your help, I had some suspicion of this answer.


I just follow the tutorial that you tell me, but nothing to do, everything compiles well but the component does not get anywhere. I do other attemptice and I would come onmentment you peter again ... There is no way to export this component of delphi 7 and import it into delphi berlin?

thank you very much

Comment: You can't "export and import a component". You can install a component if you have the source files, which is described in the post I linked. You have to be more specific with the issue you're having. If you have trouble explaining in English go ahead and use French, much of what you wrote above makes no sense what so ever ...

Comment: Merci pour votre aide

Alors dans un premier temps j’ai téléchargé les fichiers de cette adresse comme indiqué dans le post :
[Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RadStudio_XE6/Object%20Pascal/VCL/ShellControls/)

J’ai cette erreur :
[C1](http://hpics.li/3d15b13)

[j’ai suivi ces indications page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE6/en/VCL.ShellControls_Sample)
et j’obtiens aussi une erreur : 
[C2](http://hpics.li/2380d0d)

Surement un problème d’encodage (unicode), mais là çà me dépasse.

MERCI

Comment: C'est pas necessaire de télécharger des fichiers; ils se trouvent déjà à "[ProgramFiles]\Embarcadero\Studio\[...]\source\vcl\". Comme décrivé dans l'autre post, il faut créer un package nouveau (File -> New -> Package), ajouter Vcl.Shell.ShellConsts.pas & Vcl.Shell.ShellCtrls.pas, après ajouter la procedure Register dans ShellCtrls (voir l'autre post), et finalement installer le package.

Comment: Merci beaucoup, tout fonctionne maintenant avec les fichiers présents.