# Read INI File in a thread without consuming CPU time

Tags: multithreading, delphi, ini

How can I read an `.ini` file in a thread without consuming so much CPU time? The thread will run at runtime, this means while true without delay.

The code to search the value on .ini is:

```
var
  Leitura : TIniFile;
begin
  Result  := False;
  Leitura := TIniFile.Create('File.ini');

  if Leitura.ValueExists('KEY', ValueToSearch) then Result := True;

  Leitura.Free;
```

but since this function runs in an infinite loop, it consumes CPU time, and I need solve this question.

Comment: Why are you reading the INI file in a continuous loop? Your high CPU usage likely means your thread is not yielding to other threads between loop iterations. Try adding a small `Sleep()` on each iteration. Though you might consider finding another solution that doesn't involve continuously reading an INI file

Comment: Just like any thread, if it doesn't sleep for at least a few msec, then as Remy says, it will consume an entire CPU core.

Comment: Create a huge ini on a slow disk, disable read cache if the controller allows. Then you might substitute cpu usage with disk trashing. Or, try asking the ["X"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem.

Comment: i read to check if a  key exist on .ini or no, the routine are used on a loop who check windows handles, to determine if a specific handle are on .ini or no.

Comment: @DouglasRuiz At least use `TMemIniFile` instead of `TIniFile` so you can load the INI into memory, then reload the file only when it changes on disk.  That will remove unnecessary disk I/O overhead from your loop's processing.  Then just `Sleep()` the thread periodically while looping.

Comment: i solved my problem using tstringlist.loadfromfile and analysing the lines, but later i test your solution.

Comment: That's not a solution to your problem.

Comment: Using a `TStringList` instead of a `TIniFile` has absolutely nothing to do with thread responsiveness. You'll have the precise same issue. As I said in my prior comment: "Just like any thread, if it doesn't sleep for at least a few msec, then as Remy says, it will consume an entire CPU core."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of continuously polling the .INI file for changes you could monitor the file for changes using the [FindFirstChangeNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/FileAPI/nf-fileapi-findfirstchangenotificationa) API and only check the value when the file has changed. [Earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905926/where-is-tshelltreeview) Delphi versions contained a component `TShellChangeNotifier` in the unit `ShellCtrls.pas` which was a wrapper around the API function. There is furthermore an article [A Directory Monitor Class For Delphi](http://www.osnews.com/story/7376/A-Directory-Monitor-Class-For-Delphi/) that shows how to use the [ReadDirectoryChangesW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw) Windows API function. `ReadDirectoryChangesW` "retrieves information that describes the changes within the specified directory". The Delphi JCL contains a component [TJvChangeNotify](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvChangeNotify) to monitor file and directory changes, too. On Torry you can finally find a component [ATFileNotification](https://torry.net/pages.php?id=252) that allows to watch for file/directories changes and to fire an event when change occurs.

Comment: i already used him to anothers solutions on paste i'll try with him or maybe IPC.